# Autofac: accessing dependent object type at resolve time

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, constructor, dependency-injection, autofac

I have two objects like this:

```
public class A : IA
{
    public A (Type depedentType)
    {
    }
}

public class B : IB
{
    public B (IA a) { } // dependent on A
}
```

How can I pass type of B to constructor of A at resolve time?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new A(p.TypedAs<Type>)).As<IA>();

builder.Register(c => new B(c.Resolve<IA>(TypedParameter.From(typeof(B))))).As<IB>();
```